# Api to accept written number as option?

Tags: node.js, captcha

I have using azcapture api which only accepts number as id at the end of 'path' Options of Fetch/Request api and works when I type in the id e.g.

```
Var options = {
   'path':'url+key+1234455
}
```

When 1234455 is typed like above it works. But since this is the resp I cannot beforehand know the id so I pass it from the req result which was a POST and now I do a GET, effectively I have chained them without using Promises:

```
 Function secondCall(id)
    Console.log (id)
    Var options = { 'path': url+key+id
    }
```

This above always fails even if I parse id with parseInt or Number () or if I parse or coerce then

```
 id.toString()
```

since ClientRequestArgs.path is a string (ClientRequestArgs.path?: string), I believe, it always resolves to a string.

Am I seeing double here or is there a fundamental issue?

POSTMAN works fine btw and the code I have below is exported from POSTMAN except in chainResolve function the first 4 lines are my conversion code.

If I change this line and replace the resolvedID to a pre generated id it will work:
url: 'http://azcaptcha.com/res.php?key=some_azcaptcha_apikey&action=get&id=335439890',

But as resolvedID the converted string (pre generated id) into an int it won't work.

Full code with keys omitted:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('follow-redirects').http;
var axios = require('axios');

var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'http://azcaptcha.com/in.php?key=key&method=post',
  'headers': {
  },
  formData: {
    'file': {
      'value': fs.createReadStream('C:/Users/jsonX/Documents/fiverr/captchatest.png'),
      'options': {
        'filename': 'C:/Users/jsonX/Documents/fiverr/captchatest.png',
        'contentType': null
      }
    }
  }
};

//let respondedID;
convertToInt = (x) => {
    var converted=parseInt(x[1], 10); 
    return converted;
} 

request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  var respondedID = response.body;
  console.log('line 26 '+respondedID);
  chainResolve(respondedID);

});


chainResolve = (id) => {
    var sid = id.split('|');
    var resolvedID=parseInt(sid[1], 10)
    console.log(parseInt(sid[1], 10));
    console.log('line 40 '+convertToInt(sid));

    var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://azcaptcha.com/res.php?key=key&action=get&id=resolvedID',
      headers: { }
    };
    
    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! It turns out this API will not give you back any result if the resp is CAPTCHA_NOT_READY. So the solution was to set a timeout and push this with a callback in my response block of the second request:

```
axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      if (result === 'CAPCHA_NOT_READY'){
                console.log('Captcha is being processed');  
                var startTime = setTimeout(function() {
                waitR(id);
                    clearTimeout(startTime);
                },5000);
            } else {
                console.log(result.split('|')[1]);
            }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

waitR = (id) => {
    console.log('The result is being processed ...');
    chainResolve(id);
}
```